# Spring boot 2.0.0.RC1fails to access info endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I just updated my spring boot dependency from 2.0.0.M7 to 2.0.0.RC1. 
Every things was working perfectly before. However now I am getting error i.e whenever i am trying to access info endpoint.

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'commit.id' to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>`

I have set the application.yml as

```
   management:
    info:
      git:
       enabled: true
       mode: full
```

The RC1 docs has the same config.

Comment: Add more information to the question please

Comment: I was able to recreate this issue, 
    `Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>]
 at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem's caused by a [regression](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11892) in Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1 when the git mode is set to `full`. You can work around the problem by removing the `mode: full` line from your YAML file.

Comment: This fix is part of Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC2 release. Until then I just removed the FULL value.